# clearInteval don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I use setInterval and clearInterval in js, when 1st page load

```
var timer_detail=setInterval(function page1_load(){            
......
},5000);
```

When I go to 2nd page

```
function page2_load(){
  clearInterval(timer_detail);
}
```

but timer don't stop and I don't know why?

Comment: How do you mean "second page"? Loading a whole new page will put all the JS that ran on the first page out of scope.

Comment: `clearInterval` works just fine, if used correctly .. but I'm unsure as to what "page+2" is supposed to mean, or in what context is is running from.

Comment: Have you really chosen `page+2_load()` as an identifier?

Comment: I puts js function in event onload
In page 1, <body onload="function to set timer">
IN page 2, <body onload="function to stop timer">
When I go to page 2, it don't stop timer

Comment: Then stop the timer before they change pages

Comment: @Greeen - What is the evidence? How do you get page two to have the `timer_detail`?

Comment: In page 2, f12 > tab network and I see page1_load still work every 5s

Comment: @Green - Timers are not carried over from page to page. That would be a security risk.

Comment: What if I use ajax in function page1_load ? I don't know why but timer work in all page.

Comment: If `var timer_detail=setInterval(...` runs in both pages it doesn't matter what you name your function it will run. So the only way to clear it is to make sure that the `page2_load` is called as user3117255 did.

Comment: fwiw Im assuming that `var timer_detail=setInterval` is in both pages because @Green said it continues to run when the second page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Make the interval variable global replacing:

```
var timer_detail = ...
```

with

```
window.timer_detail = ...
```

This should fix any scope issues but if it doesn't then add an alert to the `page2_load` function to ensure the function is being executed when expected.

```
function page2_load(){
    alert('page2_load');
    clearInterval(timer_detail);
}
```

Comment: @Green Did the alert fire? I don't think `setInterval` does what you think it does.

Answer (score -1):

One the second page add

```
<body onload="page2_load()">
```

this will executed your function.

please not that I also got ride of the "+" in the function name. because you cant have symbols in a function name.

it should be

```
function page2_load(){clearInterval(timer_detail)}
```

Comment: Intervals are **not** carried over from page to page. Not sure why you took the white space out of the function.

Comment: assuming `var timer_detail=setInterval(function page1_load(){` lives in both pages it would actually start in both cases. So this answer is technically valid. All you have to do is call `page2_load`